# Using random forest when not all the observations have data

Tags: random-forest

I have this given database:

[image]

I would like to predict column "y" using the columns "index_1","index_2","index_3" using the random forest classifier.

as you can see, column "size: does not have values for each observation.

**My question is : Can I still use random forest classifier when I don't have data for all the observations, and if yes, is it ok?should I give value (e.g "noData") to the empty cells? will it harm the prediction? or maybe no need?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory decision trees (and random forests) are able to deal with missing values in the data. But whether a particular implementation of the algorithm allows this (and how to use it with this implementation) depends on the specific package.

Answer (score 1):

Since size seems to be a categorical variable you can just go ahead and treat all blank values as an additional variable level. This is regardless of the specific algorithm you're using.